# ASP.NET - any service bus technology?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msmq, nservicebus

I have a shared hosting, and it supports MSMQ. I host my ASP.NET MVC websites on it. I want to build a service that can queue messages and handle them, and maybe some other websites on the same hosting with access to the MSMQ to handle these messages.

I know about NServiceBus (I use it in my workplace), but as far as I know it is run as a windows service.

What I'm looking for is something that is suitable to be used on websites hosting? is there such thing? the website host should be the "service"...

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you can run NServiceBus in your own process: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting-nservicebus-in-your-own-process-v4.x

Comment: What is the quesdtion here? YOu fail to ask one. You have MSMQ - why deal with NService Bus at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seconding @PhilSandler's comment - you can host NServiceBus in your ASP.NET processes and have them talk to each other without any windows services.

Comment: is this http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting-nservicebus-in-your-own-process the right article to read?

Comment: Yup - that's the place to get started.